# Dynamic table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a really weird and complex requirement that I need help with. I have a table let's say `Tasks` that contains all the tasks for a user/system. I need to filter out the tasks per user and show it in UI. But here is the scene, the `Tasks` table contains a column `base_table` that stores the table name (real SQL Server table) on which it is based. It also stores the `base table id` which navigates to a particular record in the base table. Now I need to add some filter in the base table and if it satisfies the task would get retrieved.

I did try to put up a procedure which would hit a select query against base table and also check conditions.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE gautam_dtTable_test 
    (@TableName AS nvarchar(max))
AS 
BEGIN try 
    declare @sql nvarchar(max)
    declare @ret tinyint

    set @ret = 0
    set @sql = 'select 1 where exists (Select top 1 Id from ' + @TableName+' where some_condition)';

    Exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@var tinyint out', @ret out

    return @ret
end try
begin catch
    return 0
end catch
```

I have used the procedure to input table name and hit some conditions and return a flag, 1/0 kind of thing. I also want to use try catch so that if there is any error, it would return false.

That's why I have used the procedure, not function. But seems like we can use this procedure into sql statement. Overall what I have in my mind is

```
Select * 
from tasks 
where some_conditions 
  and procedure/function_to_check(tasks.base_table)
```

#### Key issues with my approach

1. The base_table name could be invalid, so are some columns in it. So, I would love to use a try-catch.
2. Need to Embed it as sub-query to avoid parallel operations. But it seems tough when your procedure/function have **EXEC** and **sp_executesql** defined.

Any kind of help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `select a.x, b.y, c.z from a left join b on a.table_name = 'b' and a.id = b.id left join c on a.table_name = 'c' and a.id = c.id`

Comment: @ta.speot.is I think you misunderstood. The table b, c would be mentioned in table a. So, it could be dynamic, any table in db.

Comment: Yikes this is a scary procedure. You really should be using sysname as the datatype for your parameter instead of nvarchar(max). And you should use QUOTENAME to wrap your parameter value with square brackets. This is not only a better approach in case you have a space in the name but it will also help safeguard this against sql injection.

Comment: And where is @var in your dynamic sql? You have gone to the trouble of defining it and passing it as an output parameter but is missing from your query. I am afraid you have obfuscated your data structures so much it has made your question extremely difficult to understand the issue.

Comment: @SeanLange Apologies for the issues. They would of course cause problems. I am just trying out a POC with not much experience with procedures. I even don't know if it would work. The idea is if I can build a SQL query to fetch/check something in base_table and if I can use it as sub-query? Obviously there are some security flaws. Should I know if there is a way out, I'll fix them.

Comment: This is still so vague it is nearly impossible to provide a real answer. I believe that what you are trying is possible.

Comment: @SeanLange thanks. But could you check my edited question and provide your view on any way around?

Comment: I don't understand what the issue is. You have some pseudocode that albeit rather scary seems logically close to what you are describing you want to happen. I can't help you with an answer because I don't know what the question is.

Comment: @GautamKumarSamal I understand, I'm just saying save yourself the hassle and do it that way. i.e. find a better way to structure your data and you have solutions to this problem!

Answer (score 0):

The question as stated is a bit unclear so I am going to make some assumptions here.  It looks like you are trying achieve the following:

First it seems you are trying to only return task in your task table where the ‘base_table’ column value references a valid SQL Server table.

Secondly if I understand the post correctly, based on the where clause condition passed to the tasks table you are trying to determine if the same columns exists in your base table.

The first part is certainly doable. However, the second part is not since it would require the query to somehow parse itself to determine what columns are being filtered on.
The following query show how you can retrieve only tasks for which there is a valid corresponding table.

```
SELECT      *
FROM        [dbo].[tasks] ts
CROSS APPLY (
                SELECT [name] 
                FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('[dbo].' + QUOTENAME(ts.base_table)) AND type in (N'U')
            ) tb
```

If the field(s) you are trying to filter on is known up front (i.e. you are not trying to parse based of the tasks table) then you can modify the above query to pass the desired columns you want to check as follow:

```
DECLARE @columnNameToCheck NVARCHAR(50) = 'col2'

SELECT      ts.*
FROM        [dbo].[tasks] ts
CROSS APPLY (
                SELECT [name] 
                FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('[dbo].' + QUOTENAME(ts.base_table)) AND type in (N'U')
            ) tb
CROSS APPLY (
                SELECT [name] 
                FROM sys.columns WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('[dbo].' + QUOTENAME(ts.base_table)) AND [name] = @columnName
```